# How to use volley without context or an alternative for composable context?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-volley, android-jetpack

The `val queue` needs a **context** and I have to use a context and so I have to use the @Composable so I can write the `val context`. but the problem is that where I want to use this function, there is not inside a Composable, so I can't use this function.

How can I write a **volley** request wihtout context or tell me an alternative way to write context here?

```
    @Composable
  fun MyMainVolley() {

  val context = LocalContext.current
  val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

  val url = "https://rezaapp.downloadseriesmovie.ir/maintxt.php"
  val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    { response ->
       baseUrl = response
    },
    { println("That didn't work!") })
 queue.add(stringRequest)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `Context` as parameter.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun test1() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val response = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(){
        Button(
           onClick = { MyMainVolley(context,response) }
        ){
        Text("Start volley")
        }
    

       Text(response.value)
    }
}

fun MyMainVolley(
    context: Context,
    result: MutableState<String>
) {

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

    val url = "https://rezaapp.downloadseriesmovie.ir/maintxt.php"
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        { response ->
            result.value = response
        },
        { println("That didn't work!") })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. when I use the MyMainVolley() function, I get the error: Expecting a top level declaration. I want to use this function on top of my retrofit interface, to make my baseurl changable from my php file. is it possible? is my method a good way for doing my goal?